# Apache Hop Rest Client Transform

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, apache-hop

I am new to apache Hop and was building a pipeline. I am stuck at a point where the transform is Rest Client. I am making a get request to my api and the json response is being saved in a result field. Now I want to access the fields inside this json and I am not able to find a way/transform so that I can access my json fields in next transform of pipeline. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet of what you are trying. That could help to get your answers fast and clear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured it out and therefore, posting my answer here.

The Rest Transform actually provide the Json result in "result" variable, and this variable is string.

The hop transform that extracts the fields of a string(json structure) is **"JSON input"** and you have to provide the path in fields tab of this transform.

Therefore, anyone struggling with same can use JSON INPUT transform.